A question about data manipulation of a dataframe
I have a column "Both languages" that is the result of passing Python's zip function to the columns "Supported languages" (col directly extracted from Steam's database, that includes every language available for every game in Steam) and "Languages" (ad-hoc column that contains the top 10 most popular languages in Steam games).
My question is a bit complicated to formulate, so I decided to put an example of what I want to accomplish instead. Hope you don't mind.
Example:
Second row of the column "Both languages" (remember: 1st list = Steam languages, 2nd list = top 10 languages):
(['English', 'French', 'Italian', 'German', 'Spanish - Spain', 'Japanese', 'Portuguese - Brazil', 'Russian', 'Simplified Chinese', 'Traditional Chinese']", ['English', 'Simplified Chinese', 'Russian', 'Spanish - Spain', 'Portuguese - Brazil', 'German', 'Japanese', 'French', 'Polish', 'Korean'])

Result that I want to achieve (each language would be a new column in the dataframe):
'English', 'Simplified Chinese', 'Russian', 'Spanish - Spain', 'Portuguese - Brazil', 'German', 
    1                 1              1              1                   1                 1
'Japanese', 'French', 'Polish', 'Korean'
     1          1         0         0

So basically what I want is for every language in top 10, put a 1 if it is in the first list, a 0 if it is not, and remove all the languages of the first list that are not even represented in top 10 list.
I attached some images to help understanding.



Thank you very much in advance.
I tried different things by myself and assisted for an AI but none seemed to solve the problem. In fact some solutions have generated other problems.

If the top 10 languages is simply the top 10 languages for all games on steam, and thereby does not change by game, then it is just a list and does not need to be it's own column:
top_10_langs = ['English', 'Simplified Chinese', 'Russian', 'Spanish - Spain', 
    'Portuguese - Brazil', 'German', 'Japanese', 'French', 'Polish', 'Korean']

To convert the supported languages to a list of 0s and 1s, you can use .apply and do a membership check in top_10_langs.  Removing the non-top-10 languages is a similar method.  I am not use a set here to preserve the order.
df = pd.DataFrame({'SupportedLanguages': [
    ['English', 'French', 'Italian', 'Spanish - Spain', 'Portuguese - Brazil'], 
    ['English', 'French', 'German', 'Spanish - Spain'], 
    ['English', 'Hindi', 'Bengali'], 
    ['English', 'Traditional Chinese', 'Vietnamese', 'Korean']
]})

df_out = pd.DataFrame({
    'SupportedLangs0or1': df['SupportedLanguages'].apply(
         lambda langs: [1*(x in langs) for x in top_10_langs]
     ),
    'SupportLangsInTop10': df['SupportedLanguages'].apply(
        lambda langs: [x for x in langs if x in top_10_langs]
    )
})

This give the output data frame as:
df_out
# returns:
               SupportedLangs0or1                                SupportLangsInTop10
0  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  [English, French, Spanish - Spain, Portuguese ...
1  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]         [English, French, German, Spanish - Spain]
2  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]                                          [English]
3  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]                                  [English, Korean]

